# How to perform deep clone with React setState?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, setstate, deep-copy

I'm trying to deep clone a BST object with its own class and functions and use it's functions to rerender in a React component after I call its functions. However, React setState doesn't support deep clone so the functions are not passed in the state.

How can I achieve/fix this?

```
const runBuildTree = (n) => {
  const BST = new BinarySearchTree();
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    BST.insert(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100));
    setOutput(structuredClone(BST));
  }
  setOutput(structuredClone(BST));
};

const handleDelete = () => {
  output.remove(delNode);
};

useEffect(() => {
  //rendering BST with dependency of output
}, [output]);
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do whatever you want o do with `BST`, and when you are done, then change the state

```
const runBuildTree = (n) => {
  const BST = new BinarySearchTree();
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    BST.insert(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100));
    // setOutput(structuredClone(BST));
  }
  setOutput(structuredClone(BST)); // after you are done then setState
};
```